# CouchDB: transparency when connecting to replicated databases

Tags: couchdb, replication

Let's say I have set up continuous bidirectional replication in CouchDB:

HostA <-> HostB.

As far as I understand, this is the simplest master-master replication - so both HostA and HostB accept reads and writes. Is it possible for the client to be transparet on which database he operates? I use Ektorp as a Java driver for CouchDB. When I initialize the connection I have to provide the IP address, for example http://HostA.mydomain.com:5984. What happens when this host is actually down? I would like to achieve transparency, like in RavenDB's client library - when HostA is down, it tries to connect to the other replicated hosts (http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/bundles/how-client-integrates-with-replication-bundle).

In other words - is CouchDB aware of its replication targets so that the client doesn't have to manually choose the currently-alive host?

Comment: You can inspect the contents of the [`_replicator` database](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/replication/replicator.html). It has information about the running replications, so you can use that information to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use a load balancer like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/). HAproxy is commonly used with web application servers, but can be used with any server that uses HTTP. You can find an [example configuration in the couchdb repo](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/rel/haproxy.cfg).